# Objective C Class Extension Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

As far as I have understood , class extensions are used to declare private methods in objective C . But I found this happening.

//Person.m

```
@interface Person()

- (void)someMethod;

@end

@implementation

- (void)someMethod
{
    NSLog(@"base class method");
}
```

If I subclass this and declare the same function in the .h file of the subclass.
//SubPerson.h

```
@interface SubPerson : Person

- (void)someMethod;

@end
```

I do not provide a definition for this method in the .m file (SubPerson.m)

I then create a derived class instance and call the method someMethod() in some file and I observe that the base class method is called.
Can someone please explain ?

Comment: This is called inheritance and its a concept from Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Yes I know about inheritance but you cannot inherit private methods, right ? And the definition of extension says it is used to declare private methods ?

Comment: on this regard, @mipadi's answer is quite accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Visibility is only used by the compiler. The Objective-C runtime itself does not prevent you from calling private methods. Objective-C methods do not have the notion of public, private, and protected that, e.g., Java does; effectively, all methods are "public" (at least in the Java sense).

Comment: you save my life! agree

Comment: I am only comparing my C++ knowledge here . C++ wouldn't allow my private method to be called through a derived class object.

Comment: @PreethamBaliga: Yeah, Objective-C doesn't have the same notion of private methods that C++ has.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, where you put the method headers/@interface blocks defines the visibility of the methods. Since the superclass has `someMethod` as private, but the subclass has it as public, the subclass effectively has the method header as both private and public, so the public visibility takes precedence since it is the only visibility level that allows both private and public visibility to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is called inheritance and it's a concept from Object Oriented Programming. You are just making the superclass method visible on the subclass here.

If you overwrite this method *and it were a public method*, it would not call the superclass equivalent unless you call `[super someMethod]` inside `subPerson`'s `someMethod` implementation.

Comment: Calling [super someMethod] gives a compile error :(

Comment: Sorry i edited the answer, since the compiler doesn't recognizes it as a public method it wont let you call super.

Comment: No issues, So basically the private thing is only for the compiler and not the runtime , right ?

Comment: Yes. you should consider accepting @mipadi's :)
As a comparison, Objective-C is weak typed, you can create an id object that's like a wild card and store anything in it. If you store an NSString and try to call the NSArray method `count` it would give an exception at runtime, but it would still compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here , you have define someMethod () in person class as public and Person class is subclass by SubPerson class. So SubPerson class should contain all public properties and methods. That's why you can call someMethod from SubPerson class